# how to set font-awesome check icon when click then check

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

i want to set font-awesome check icon that when ic click on it then its check when i click again its uncheck how this is possible .... i not use checkbox so plz tell me in this font-awesome check ....if its possible with jquery then tell me plzz how its done..
my code ....

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul> 
  <li> 
   <label> first
      <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </label>
  </li>
  <li> 
   <label> second
      <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </label>
  </li>
  <li> 
   <label> third
      <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </label>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's possible, these are the methods you need to research: http://api.jquery.com/click and http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass. Also note that you should only include jQuery once, and your first `<script>` tag should be within the `<head>` of the document

Comment: thanks but plzz i am new can you tell me what i do

Comment: Please show respect to other users - it says a lot if you can't be bothered to type the word "please".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#box1").click(function() {
  $("#box1").css("display", "none");
  $("#check1").css("display", "block");

});
$("#check1").click(function() {
  $("#box1").css("display", "block");
  $("#check1").css("display", "none");

});

$("#box2").click(function() {
  $("#box2").css("display", "none");
  $("#check2").css("display", "block");

});
$("#check2").click(function() {
  $("#box2").css("display", "block");
  $("#check2").css("display", "none");

});
$("#box3").click(function() {
  $("#box3").css("display", "none");
  $("#check3").css("display", "block");

});
$("#check3").click(function() {
  $("#box3").css("display", "block");
  $("#check3").css("display", "none");

});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><style>#check1,
#check2,
#check3 {
  display: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        #check1, #check2, #check3 {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                first
      <i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="box1"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true" id="check1"></i>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                second
               <i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="box2"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true" id="check2"></i>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                third
      <i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" id="box3"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true" id="check3"></i>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
    <script>
        $("#box1").click(function () {
            $("#box1").css("display", "none");
            $("#check1").css("display", "block");

        });
        $("#check1").click(function () {
            $("#box1").css("display", "block");
            $("#check1").css("display", "none");

        });

        $("#box2").click(function () {
            $("#box2").css("display", "none");
            $("#check2").css("display", "block");

        });
        $("#check2").click(function () {
            $("#box2").css("display", "block");
            $("#check2").css("display", "none");

        });
        $("#box3").click(function () {
            $("#box3").css("display", "none");
            $("#check3").css("display", "block");

        });
        $("#check3").click(function () {
            $("#box3").css("display", "block");
            $("#check3").css("display", "none");

        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Happy Coding :)**

```js
$('li').click(function() {
$(this).find('label i').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul> 
  <li> 
   <label> first
      <i class="fa fa-check-square hidden" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </label>
  </li>
  <li> 
   <label> second
      <i class="fa fa-check-square hidden" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </label>
  </li>
  <li> 
   <label> third
      <i class="fa fa-check-square hidden" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </label>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to let the checkboxes toggle:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label> first
      <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label> second
      <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label> third
      <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function asign_click_functions() {
    $(".fa-check-square").click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("fa-check-square").addClass("fa-check-square-o");
      asign_click_functions();
    });
    $(".fa-check-square-o").click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("fa-check-square-o").addClass("fa-check-square");
      asign_click_functions();
    });
  };
  asign_click_functions();
</script>

</html>
```

The thing is to reasign the click function after the action. In this case if simply reasign that for every checkbox, but that could also be done in a more elegant way.